# histplot is showing data grouped in pairs

Tags: python, seaborn, histplot

I'm trying to create a histoplot to show a certain column of my dataframe that I'm sure has values for every single integer going from 47 to 93 but when I plot it it leaves spaces every two values. I'm not sure if this is intended behavior and in case it is how I'd go about changing it?

`sns.histplot(data['overall'])`
[image]

Comment: You can set `discrete=True` in the call to `sns.histplot(....)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `bins` to all the unique values:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'overall' : [item for sublist in [[x]*x for x in range(1, 11)] for item in sublist]})
sns.histplot(data['overall'], bins=data['overall'].unique())
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to pass both `bins` and `discrete`; `discrete` is a manner of setting the bins.